# Observing particles without photons

Tags: particle-physics, photons, electrons, experimental-technology

Can particle physicists in a lab observe a particle, with electrons orbiting, in a vacuum without putting a photon on it (without inserting any electromagnetic energy so we don't disturb the position of the electrons orbiting the particle)? 
If they can do that, how does it happen and what will the position of the electron be ?

If they can't do that, how can we know what's the original state of the electrons before disturbing its original position with photons ?

Or do they observe the particle along with electrons, using photons, thus observing a false position of how the electron was, before the photon hits, and then calculating the original position of the electron using known equations?

i know my language is non-technical and crude but it has a valid point i think!!!

Comment: please see the answers  here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303298/how-can-we-see-measure-detect-particles-during-experiments

Comment: also these :  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292174/particle-detector-de-dx-and-momentum-resolution  , http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/cloud-chamber-video-showing-large-particles-what-are-they  ,http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160257/how-are-quarks-and-leptons-detected-experimentally

Comment: Note that, even without physicists intentionally putting photons in, black body radiation exists inside the vacuum system.

Comment: Neutrinos are detected because they interact weakly with ordinary matter and then we measure the disturbed ordinary matter through electromagentic means, which sorta meets your requirements while violating the spirit of the question. Short reason: because only electromagnetism and gravity have effects at significant distance (including the human scale) we can *only* observe things using those interactions.

Comment: my bad, i didn't right my question well enough. i didn't mean any exotic sub-atomic particles i only meant a particle, whatever it may be "Na", with electrons orbiting it...
i encourage rereading the question after the edits